# how to avoid duplication users in my db with php

Tags: php, mysqli

How are you all,

hope every one here is OK,

now I have a form that the admin can create users and he can delete users as will let me display the code first

this is my code

```
> > <?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
> 
> session_start();
>   if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) ||
> $_SESSION['login']!='1' )         {
>       header("Location:loginpage.php");
>       } ?>
> 
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
> XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
> <html
> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
> content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
> <title>My Control panel</title> <link
> href="../css_style.css"
> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
> </head>
> 
> 
> 
> <body> <div id="werpper"> <div
> id="content">
> 
> <div id="header">My control -
> Panel</div> <div id="body_cntent">  
> <div id="left_side">   <p>Home and
> instructions</p>   <p><a
> href="../control_panel.php">main
> directory</a></p>   <p><a
> href="add_event.php">Add new
> event</a></p>   <p><a
> href="../editoccasion.php">Control
> Occasion's</a></p>   <p><a
> href="add_photos_and_occasion.php">Add
> Photos_occasion</a></p>   <p><a
> href="../signout.php">Sign out</a></p>
> </div> <div id="right_side">
> 
> <h2>Add new user</h2>
> 
> <form action="" method="post">
> 
> <table width="600" border="0"
> cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">  
> <tr>
>     <td width="78">User name</td>
>     <td width="2">&nbsp;</td>
>     <td width="149"><input type="text" name="uname" value="" /></td>
>     <td width="332" rowspan="5" align="left" valign="top"><p
> class="red">For Administration use
> only.</p>
>       <p>You can add or delete users from <a
> href="edit_users.php">here</a><br />
>         You can't edit any user if you like to change any user account you
> can delete the user and create it
> again with the new
> information.</p></td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>Password</td>
>     <td>&nbsp;</td>
>     <td><input type="text" name="pass" value="" /></td>
>     </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>&nbsp;</td>
>     <td>&nbsp;</td>
>     <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add user" /></td>
>     </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>&nbsp;</td>
>     <td>&nbsp;</td>
>     <td>&nbsp;</td>
>     </tr>   <tr>
>     <td>&nbsp;</td>
>     <td>&nbsp;</td>
>     <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
>     </tr> </table> </form>
> 
> </div> </div>
> 
> <div id="footer"></div> </div> </div>
> 
> <?php
>       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
>               include_once "../config/config.php";
>               $uname = $_POST['uname'];       $pass =$_POST['pass'];
>               $check = "select * from users where id = {$uname}";         $result_check
> = $db->query($check)or die($db->error);
>       
>               while ($row = $result_check -> fetch_object()) {
>                       if(num_rows == 1){
>               
>               echo "error";
>               
>               }else{
>               $add_user = "insert into users (id, uname, pass) values ('',
> '$uname', '$pass')";
>               $result = $db -> query($add_user) or die ("$db->error");
>               if ($result) {
>                       echo "user added successfuly";
>                       }else{
>               
>               echo "There was an error please try again later";
>               
>               }           }       }   } ?>
> 
> </body> </html>
```

all I need here to know is how to solve the problem of this code

```
$check = "select * from users where id = {$uname}";
        $result_check = $db->query($check)or die($db->error);


        while ($row = $result_check -> fetch_object()) {

            if(num_rows == 1){

                echo "error";

                }
```

how can I avoid duplication users in my db

Comment: I will review this again when I go home but any help will be praiseworthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which database library you're using and what all its methods are, so I made this with plain mySQL for if you went the route of making the `uname` (username) field a `UNIQUE INDEX` --

```
// instantiate database connection
$db = mysql_connect( .. );

// assuming the id field is auto incrementing, it can be left out of the query
$add_user  = "INSERT INTO users (uname, pass) ";
$add_user .= "VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($uname) . "', ";
$add_user .= "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($pass) . "')";

if (mysql_query($add_user, $db))
{ 
    if (mysql_affected_rows($db) == 1)
    {
        // New user added, do something
    }
} 
else
{ 
    if (mysql_errno($db) == 1062) 
    { 
        // Duplicate username, do something 
    } 
    else
    { 
        // A different database error occurred
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.stealthyninja for your help but I am using php5 and MYSQLI and there is something known as 'count' and this is the solution  for the problem I have but I don't remember how to use it please see this on php http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.field-count.php

Answer (score 1):

Most DBs have some way of making columns or combinations of unique.  Simply set up a unique constraint on whichever column you want to make unique.

If there are already users in there that aren't unique, you will have to cleam them out of the database first.

Comment: Yes I know this sir but I'd like to make something with the php not with the MYSQL I don't want the error to come from the database I want the php to check this and echo the error that I put if there is a error. Thanks Again sir for trying helping me

Comment: PHP is capable of catching the SQL error and handling it however you see fit.  How you do it will depend on how PHP is interfacing with the database (MySQL, MySQLi, PDO, etc), but all the interfacing mechanisms provide ways of dealing with SQL errors.  Using a constraint si really the correct way of doing it, anything else would be a sticking plaster solution at best.

Answer (score 1):

OK just found my answer on stack overflow I love this site and all the people there

this is the answer

```
$check = $db->query("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE uname='$uname'");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0) {
                die('username already taken');
```

it is very simple and also it uses the same concept of the count() and if some one know something about the count please write it to us

Thanks all, and regards,
Yousef Altaf

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent duplicate users in your database, just do a select similar to the one you have listed before the INSERT checking to see if the user exists.  Another way however, a worse approach would be to add a UNIQUE constraint on the field in the database then your INSERT will fail upon duplication.

Comment: Why would a unique constraint be worse?  It would be more reliable for a start, as it would also prevent users added manually, say through phpmyadmin, from being duplicates.

Comment: I said it would be worse just for the sheer fact that if you are archiving old users, then the same username could never be reused, unless you have the UNIQUE constraint on a set of fields.

Comment: Just the same sir I want something like this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.field-count.php check this on php and there is a solution but I don't remember how it can be done Thanks judda